# Local Docker run fails (An assembly specified in the manifest was not found)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nuget, dockerfile

I am trying to test my local Docker build before I deploy to AWS. My app has dependencies to AWSSDK.Core via NuGet and I am using the following Docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2.0-aspnetcore-runtime AS runtime
WORKDIR /My.App
COPY bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2 . 
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5000
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "My.App.dll"]
```

To build my file

```
docker build -t myapp .
```

However, when I try to run it with

```
docker run -it --rm --name my_app myapp
```

I get the error

```
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (My.App.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'AWSSDK.Core', version: '3.3.106.17'
    path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/AWSSDK.Core.dll'
```

As far as I can tell, I should be adding a RUN command to install the AWSSDK in my Docker image but I cannot find it. So, my question would be: Am I doing something wrong? If not, is there some kind of reference as to the locations of packages to use in Docker?

Answer (score 0):

After digging around some, I found a few possible answers. First I found [this blog post](https://manski.net/2016/08/docker-dotnet-core-and-nuget-dependencies/#the-problem.28s.29) which exemplifies how to use docker with .NET with a very simple project. The solution to my problem was to use the `dotnet package` command, which gathers all the dependencies and puts them in a single directory.

However, after digging some more, I found [Microsoft's Container Tools in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/overview?view=vs-2019) which, by pressing the right mouse button on the project, offers to add `Docker Support` which is more elaborate than the first solution.